# Reduce the number of lines in code in android java program

Tags: java, android

Myself sujay. I am very new to android programming. I have written a program which converts value which we use in Textile field. Some of the values are directly proportional some are indirectly proportional. I give the code that i wrote below could some help me to reduce the number of lines in the program with some other JAVA codes

```
  public void onClick(View v)
{

    int index1 = spinner11.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int index2 = spinner21.getSelectedItemPosition();
    double value = 0;
    if (from.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastmessage1),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else {
        value = Double.parseDouble(from.getText().toString());
    }
    //From Ne
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 0 )//Ne to Ne
    {
        double result = value*1;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 1) //Ne to Nm
    {
        double result = value * 1.69;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 2)//Ne to Tex
    {
        double result = 591/value;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if(index1 == 0 && index2 == 3)//Ne to kTex
    {
        double result = 0.591/value;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 4)//Ne to Denier
    {
        double result = 5314/value;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 5)//Ne to Denier
    {
        double result = 5314/value;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 6)//Ne to Denier
    {
        double result = 5314/value;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
    if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 7)//Ne to Denier
    {
        double result = 5314/value;
        to.setText(result+"");
    }
```

Comment: You can reduce a line in each if block `to.SetText(""+(value*1));` without assigning it to a local/block variable..

Answer (score 0):

This will slightly reduce the amount of lines:

```
double result = 0.0;
if (index1 == 0)//Ne to Ne
{
    if(index2 == 0)
        result = value*1;

    if (index2 == 1) 
        result = value * 1.69;

    if (index2 == 2)
        result = 591/value;

    if(index2 == 3)
       result = 0.591/value;

    if (index2 == 4 || index2 == 5 || index2 == 6 || index2 == 7)
        result = 5314/value;

}
to.setText(result+"");
```

Hope it helps